# Seem you're trying to access 'ReactNative.createClass' from the 'react-native package,

Tags: react-native

Anyone has met this error can help me. I don't understand why my program happen this error[image]

Comment: You should provide some relevant code and add some details in order to get help.

Answer (score 3):

Error message is straight forward. If you can't change it manually, You can use CodeMod (https://github.com/sibelius/codemod-RN24-to-RN25)

If all your imports are correct, then check third party modules. If you are in older version, Update the third party modules.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very descriptive - you're importing `React` from the `react-native` package, which has been incorrect since version 0.25.

Instead of:

```
import React, { Component, View, Text } from 'react-native'
```

You should have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
```

Search your codebase for that style of import, it may be that you're using a 3rd-party module which is using the old style.